# Why do so many 8-Puzzle solving algorithms use DFS instead of BFS?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, search-algorithms, trees, search-problem

I see so many 8 Puzzle Solvers use a stack instead of a queue. Why is that? If you are looking for the solution with the fewest number of moves, wouldn't the solution be at a shallower point in the tree, meaning that BFS would find it much quicker? Is there some subtlety to the problem that I'm forgetting that makes DFS a better approach?

I've been comparing performance times myself and it seems like BFS is consistently and significantly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to find *the shortest solution* to the 8-puzzle, DFS is indeed a very poor method.  It's not a matter of faster or slower; DFS is not correct (it finds *a* solution, but it's not guaranteed to be the shortest solution).  You could use BFS and that will work fine.  Even better is to use A* or some related algorithm; it will find the shortest solution even faster than BFS.

If the goal is to find *any solution* to the 8-puzzle, without regard to how many moves the solution takes, DFS is a fine method.  Actually, you could use either DFS or BFS for that.  The 8-puzzle has [only 181440 reachable states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32985305/781723), so the data structures won't grow too large.